# C3 js: Is it possible to align 2 points from end to end?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, c3.js

this is my first question here in stack overflow. 
I'm working with C3 and I'm wondering if is possible to align 2 points from end to end.
for example if in my chart I have 100 and another point -100, but I want to pass through the columns that appears in the image. 
 let me show you what I want:

I want to join/align the two-point that appears in the circle highlighted:

[image]

here is my code:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
  data: {
    columns: [
      ["data1", 30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
      ["data2", -100],
      ["data3", null, null, null, null, null, 100],
    ],
    axis: {
      y: {
        max: 365,
        min: 335,
      },
    },
    type: "bar",
    types: {
      data2: "line",
      data3: "line",
    },

    colors: {
      data1: "#f567",
      data2: "blue",
    },

    bar: {
      width: {
        ratio: 0.5, // this makes bar width 50% of length between ticks
      },
    },
    labels: {
      format: function (v, id, i, j) {
        return v;
      },
    },
    // or
    //width: 100 // this makes bar width 100px
  },
});
```

thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

I just added this part and it works

```
   line: {
        connectNull: true
      },
```